# How to check if current user email has been verified in client js file

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client side javascript needs to determine if the current user email has been verified.
Is there an easier way than to first check if the emails property is present and then check the first item in the array to see if it's property is set to true? Thanks

```
const val = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId}).emails[0].verified;
```

I know the code below can work in the html file but I need the value in the js file.

```
{{#unless currentUser.emails.[0].verified}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've defined a global helper for this purpose:

```
// return true/false depending on whether the referenced user's email has been verified
Template.registerHelper('isVerified',function(){ 
  return this.emails && this.emails[0].verified; // we're in a user context
  else return Meteor.user().emails && Meteor.user().emails[0].verified; // look at the current user
});
```

Then from blaze:

```
{{#if isVerified}}...{{/if}}
```

Or from js:

```
if ( UI._globalHelpers.isVerified() ) ...
```